# Ontario Topographic and Property Data

Tags: data, topography, canada

Looking for Ontario topographic data and property line data; willing to purchase the latter.  Shapefiles or file geodatabase files would be optimal.  In terms of topographic data, I am looking for: basic outline of Ontario, county or municipal outlines, contour data, water (lines, poly, etc), buildings, and so forth.

Comment: Can you specify further in terms of the data file format, what kind of topographic details you're looking for, software you're using etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at geogratis, which is a Canadian repository for all sorts of data http://geogratis.gc.ca/geogratis/MostPopular?lang=en  this link will guide you to data related to topographic data.

Geobase as a good collection of administrative boundaries, such as Municipalities http://www.geobase.ca/geobase/en/data/admin/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Along with the above mentioned sources, Land Information Ontario data is available, but I can't speak for its accuracy - http://www.ontario.ca/environment-and-energy/land-information-ontario. What you probably want is featured on geogratis.

Comment: I work for a local municipality.... parcels are constantly being re-zoned and split. So I wonder how accurate the parcel lines for any open/free data would be. I know the process is usually updated by MPAC and takes several months - not sure if they do it across the board for Ontario though.

Answer (score 1):

For a nice set of topographic data for Ontario, there is a fun interactive map which allows you to:

- Select various areas and zoom in at a high magnification
- Enable a variety of active layers (such as contour lines, roads, water polygons, conservation areas and so on)
- Download the selected areas into a number of formats (shp, AutoCAD DWG, DXF etc)

You will have to register with their website if you want to download the data.

http://www.geographynetwork.ca/website/obm/viewer.htm